# Click on VUE does not work correctly on component child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with VUE and I have a component called Quotation and inside I call another component (child component) called sideBarOptions which is a sidebar that is shown above the parent component with the option to hide it

From sideBarOptions **I have a property called conditions** set like this: **conditions = false** and I want to change it to true with a simple **@click** but it does not work immediately until I close sideBarOptions and at that moment the **@click** is triggered.

This is my code:

**Quotation.vue**

```
<template>
 <sideBarOptions :showSidebar=show @closeSideBar="closeSideBar"/>
</template>

export default {
 data() {
  return {
    show: false,
  }
 },
 methods: {
    closeSideBar(value) {
      this.show = value;
    },  
 }
}
```

**sideBarOptions.vue**

```
<template>
 <div @click="conditions = !conditions">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box-1">
  <label for="box-1">Aceptar</label>
 </div>

 <div class="sideBar">
  <a href="#" class="closeBtn-send-email" @click="closeSideBar()">
    <h2>Envíar Cotización</h2>
    <span>X</span>
  </a>
 </div>
</template>

export default {
 props: {
    showSidebar: Boolean
 },
 data() {
  return {
    conditions: false,
  }
 },
 methods: {
    closeSideBar() {
      this.$emit('closeSideBar', false);
    },
  }
}
```

I dont understand the reason why it changes until I close the child component. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by closing the child component? how do you close it?

Comment: It is a sidebar that I close by setting a variable to false

Comment: Please show more of your code in your parent `Quotation.vue` How do you close `sideBarOptions.vue`

Comment: @skribe Thank you, I have already put the code where I show how I close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the model on the checkbox:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="box-1" v-model="conditions">
  <label for="box-1">Aceptar</label>
</div>
```

---

also multiple elements in one component might be an issue, so wrap it in a div, presuming its just your example.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div @click="conditions = !conditions">
      <input type="checkbox" id="box-1">
      <label for="box-1">Aceptar</label>
    </div>

    <div class="sideBar">
      <a href="#" class="closeBtn-send-email" @click="closeSideBar()">
        <h2>Envíar Cotización</h2>
        <span>X</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```